# TargetedPatchingOptOut and other attributes on abstract methods

Tags: c#, .net, implementation, abstract, jit

Since, attributes such as TargetedPatchingOptOut aren't handled inside the framework, do the attributes propagate to the inherited classes during the optimization?

Eg:

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Optimize across boundaries")]
    public abstract void TestFunc();
}

public class Test : TestBase
{
    // Is re-defining attributes like these necessary?
    public override void TestFunc()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Also, does the JIT compiler (ever/always) lookup inherited attributes?

> **Note:** Although the specific functionality above can be figured out easily by examining the JIT instructions on WinDbg with a few
>   (tediously) extravagant methods, I appreciate any insights on how its
>   implemented, as **it is not impossible for the JIT compiler to behave
>   very differently for different attributes without knowing its exact
>   implementation**.

**Update:**

I made a wrong assumption that the TargetedPatchingOptOut is handled by the JIT compiler, but while it is infact handled by NGen. The answer for this specific case has been answered clearly by @Hans Passant.

I think its safe to guess, each of the internal tools utilize the attributes by the same rules as given by the AttributeUsage flag.

Comment: Virtual/abstract methods are currently not inlined. Source: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/01/20/aggressive-inlining-in-the-clr-45-jit/

Comment: And why would `virtual` methods be inlined at all? I think they shoudn't be by their very nature.

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad. Was working on TargetedPatchingOptout, and pasted in a quick extra attribute example in haste, to explicitly imply the possible difference in implementations. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Does the JIT follow these same rules? In that case, I'm curious to know how that would work when there is a conflict (same attribute, with different ctor parameters across inherited classes.)

Comment: Or do each instance of the attributes get propagated into the corresponding derivatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether an attribute is visible on a derived class by default is determined by the AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited property. Which is *false* for this attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Constructor, 
     AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class TargetedPatchingOptOutAttribute : Attribute {
    // etc...
}
```

It is not exclusive, a method like Type.GetCustomAttribute() also has an *inherit* argument to allow overriding the default.

Do be careful about making assumptions about what tooling reads an attribute.  [TargetedPatchingOptOut] is almost certainly *not* read by the jitter.  It is used to determine if Ngen.exe needs to run to re-create the native image of an assembly when an update is deployed.  I don't know what the tooling looks like, the only thing that makes sense to me is that this is done on Microsoft machine in Redmond.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. Things now make sense immediately after you busted my wrong assumption of JIT handling the attribute instead of the NGen.